# How to override objective-c cateogry in swift

Tags: ios, swift2

This is my method from NSObject+AutoMagicCoding.h

```
- (id) initWithDictionaryRepresentation: (NSDictionary *) aDict;
```

This is in my bridging header

```
#import "NSObject+AutoMagicCoding.h"
```

This is my shot but failed

```
override func initWithDictionaryRepresentation(aDict: NSDictionary) -> AnyObject {}
```

Any suggests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In swift, you are not able to override convenience initializer.

Following is convenience initializer for NSObject+AutoMagicCoding so it can not be called in any initializers of sub classes.

```
- (id) initWithDictionaryRepresentation: (NSDictionary *) aDict;
```

And your following definition of initializer in Swift is wrong. you can check in interoperability between Obj-C and Swift.

```
override func initWithDictionaryRepresentation(aDict: NSDictionary) -> AnyObject {}
```

You can see this picture about rule in overriding initialisers.

[image]

For more information, you can check initialisers Section in "The Swift Programming Language" and also see Interacting with Objective-C APIs section's Initialize subsection "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C".

For init methods that begin with "initWith", the "With" also gets sliced off.

For example,

In Obj-C

```
UITableView * myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

In Swift

```
let myTableView:UITableView = UITableView(frame:CGRectZero, style:.Grouped)
```